# Robotframework : API Test :How to access a nested key:value from a json response

Tags: json, robotframework

I am trying to access the value "Tom" in the following json response

```
{
"Key1": "Value1",
"Key2": [
    {
        "id": "123",
        "name": "Scott"
    },
    {
        "id": "454",
        "name": "tom"
    }
]
}
```

I am using robotframework's requestlibrary and am new to python.  Could anyone help me get this value from the nested structure.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be something like `response.Key2[1].name`

assuming that `{"id":"123","name":"Scott"}` is at index `0`, 
 and `{"id":"454","name":"tom"}` at index `1`

Answer (score 0):

As of the current public version of Robotframework you can't access directly the sub-keys by their names (e.g. `response.Key2[1].name`) - the framework's dictionary variable resolution doesn't work at more than 1 level; that is about to change with version 3.0.3, which will be publicized shortly (mid-April 2018, according to the latest announcement).

In the mean time - and in general, you can get to it with the normal python dictionary and lists access, by using indices - that is guaranteed to work regardless of the framework's implementation.

Given the response is in this format:

```
${resp}=       Get Request   your_session     api/sample_endpoint   # the content of ${resp} is a normal string
```

, you need to convert it in python object

```
${as_json}=    To Json       ${resp}          # ${as json} is now a python's object - dictionary in your case
```

, and finally get the value using python's indices:

```
${value}=      Set Variable  ${as_json['Key2'][1]['name']}
```